# Pylint throws not-callable on decorator defined within class

Tags: python, class, decorator, pylint, callable

Im trying to create a class that has a time remaining property and executing functions within it reduces this time. Here is the code

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_remaining = 240

    @staticmethod
    def time_taken(start):
        return (datetime.now() - start).seconds

    def with_timeout(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            start = datetime.now()
            result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.time_remaining = (
                self.time_remaining - TestClass.time_taken(start)
            )
            return result

        return wrapper

    @with_timeout
    def do_something(self, param):
        # DO Something
```

Then when i instantiaite the class and use `do_something` like so:

```
test_class = TestClass()
test_class.do_something("param")
```

It works as expected. However when i run pylint on the code i get an error:

```
pylint: not-callable / f is not callable
```

Is this a false positive or is there a better way to write this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: with_timeout is being defined as a regular method of the class, the linter thinks that f will be instance (self). Try changing it to a staticmethod or moving it outside of the class?

Comment: Yeah i can see this, unsure how to resolve though. By using `@staticmethod` i get a runtime error of `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`. If i was to move it outside the class how could i control the self argument?

Comment: In the wrapper? I would be surprised if that argument was being picked up as an instance by the linter since it's not actually a normal instance method

Comment: You *should* move the function outside of the class – it's not a method, and it's not used as a ``staticmethod`` either. For the inner ``wrapper``, it doesn't matter at all where the decorator was defined.

Comment: If i make with_timeout a `@staticmethod` the linter is happy but then when i execute the code i get the above error

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if i was to move it outside of the class how would i control self `self.time_remaining`

Comment: ``self`` is bound depending on how a method is *called*, not where it is *defined*. Moving ``def with_timeout`` out of the class body won't change how ``wrapper`` works.

Comment: Perhaps a method that acts as a context manager would work instead if you really want this defined on the class. Wrap the body of each method you want to time with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Moving the method outside the class was what was required as self is bound depending on how a method is called, not where it is defined so the decorator doesn't need to be defined within the class to have access to self:

```
def time_taken(start):
    return (datetime.now() - start).seconds

def with_timeout(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.now()
        result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.time_remaining = self.time_remaining - time_taken(start)
        return result

    return wrapper


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_remaining = 240

    @with_timeout
    def do_something(self, param):
        # DO Something
```